# How much larger is the next representable value if 2^59 is stored in a double?

Tags: floating-point

This is an exam question I couldn't solve

If I store 2^59 as double, that would give me

1 * 2^58. Is the answer just 2? I.e. next value is 2^60??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the exponent.

Then look at the mantissa. It has a certain number of bits. The highest bit is not stored because it is always 1, and that bit has a value of $2^{59}$. How many bits of the mantissa are stored, and how many bits are there? Figure out the value of the lowest bit. You get the next representable number by changing that bit from 0 to 1. So how much was the value of that lowest mantissa bit again?

Comment: As an additional hint, consider what the machine epsilon for double precision floating-point numbers means.